# MS Access Query Gives Different Results in Different MDB

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have 2 Access 2003 Sp3 11.8321.8405 MDB files. Both files have the same MySQL tables attached. Both MDBs are in Access 2002/2003 format.

In one MDB (call it MDB1), I have a query that returns 193 records. In the other MDB (call it MDB2), that same query, hitting the same attached tables, returns 17 records.

I tried moving the query from one DB to the other by importing and by copying & pasting the SQL. I tried these in both directions. Each time the results are consistent.

Comment: I just tried creating a new MDB & importing the query into that. It gives the same incorrect (insufficient) results as MDB2.

Comment: How many records are in the table that you are referring to in each of the databases?  It sounds like you don't have the same data in each of the databases.

Comment: It's a join of 5 tables. Two with about 15,000 records, the other three with about 1,000.

The MDBs are all linked to the same tables on the same MYSQL server using the same ODBC connection. I used Linked Table Mgr to refresh all the linked tables and compacted & repaired all the MDBs.

Comment: Moved MDB2 to another machine and the queryappears to work correctly.

Comment: Still wondering what could be wrong with this machine.

Comment: Sounds like the ODBC connection on machine 2 has the same name as it does on the other computers, but it doesn't point to the same MySQL table.

Comment: I would have agree with **pteranodon**.  Try deleting the ODBC connection and then recreate it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. We have 2 databases - test & production. The same ODBC connection name hits either, depending upon how it's configured on the given machine. If you move a production copy of the DB down to a dev machine without re-linking all the tables, there is some underlying "confusion" going on.